# Maven reverse transitive dependency list

Tags: maven, maven-3

Is there a maven command using which I could find out list of all bundles who directly or transitively depend on a given bundle?

Comment: what do you mean by reverse? you can simply execute mvn dependency:tree find dependency list

Comment: Reverse simply means "dependent" modules on the given module.

Answer (score 0):

> mvn dependency:tree

should give you that

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I'm asking reverse of what you answered. I'm NOT asking on what bundles does a particular bundle depend, I'm asking the bundles who are depenedent on a given bundle.